# Protect assembly?

Tags: .net, security, dll, custom-controls, restrict

I have a .NET DLL (C#/VB) with custom controls, extension and other stuff.

I want that it should be available for me only.
Is there any way to restrict unauthorized access to a DLL?

Comment: You did not state what language?

Comment: @tommie I assume this is .NET

Comment: @Anton: Fair enough...but Shimmy should have added a tag to indicate what language instead of us guessing does he mean .NET or a Resource DLL in C/C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to pack/encrypt/obfuscate the DLL as Anton pointed out. And then pray that nobody will go through all the hassle of unpacking it.

The usual term for this is simply "packing".

This is what game developers do with f.ex Sony's [SecuROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Securom).

But all packing programs have the same drawbacks:

1. They can be reverse-engineered and the encryption key must be embedded in the binary
2. They usually cost money, and those that don't ([UPX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPX)) are easily unpacked.
3. Platform incompatability issues can be introduced by the unpacking process.
4. Packed binaries tend to freak Anti-viruses out.

Companies that use packers usually ship binaries that must be able to run on every thinkable computer. If you really meant it, I guess you could encrypt every single dll shipped with a unique key and then require it be ran with internet access for some challenge-response magic during the decryption phase. Overkill at any rate.

You could also make your own packer, but believe me when I say it: You don't want to go there ;)

In short, what you want is not simple to achieve even for the big players. How long does it take for a SecuROM game to show up on piratebay? So the only thing you can do is "raise the bar" and hope to go unnoticed by the good reverse-engineers.

Lastly, knowing what you're getting yourself into: Will it be worth it for you? Let's say you shipped the DLL unpacked - as it is. People will still need to reverse-engineer it to use it. Who uses undocumented 3rd-party libraries anyway? I've only done that once or twice in moments of insanity.

Comment: I don't care, it's a private program that has to be ran on 10-15 machines. I'd like to read more about encrypting and acessing encrypted DLLs.

Answer (score 3):

Well, do not redistribute the assembly in the first place. As soon as assembly is out in the wild, anybody can use it. You can make this harder by [obfuscating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code) it, but "entry points" will still be there and usable.

Theoretically, you can do something with [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Access_Security), but I'm not particularly sure this is at all possible.

Comment: It's not in the wild yet, I am looking for a way to restrict it before it reaches there...

Comment: CAS won't protect you from someone with full trust. CAS is not intended to enforce component licensing, and therefore won't do a good job at it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use licensing/copy protection tools to alter your dll. And inside the caller, you supply the required license number.

Comment: The question is how do I identify the caller of the DLL, is this possible?

Comment: you can check the calling assembly with Assembly.GetCallingAssembly

Answer (score 1):

This is not completely possible. If you want your code to run, it has to be executable. You can put in checks, packing, encryption keys, watchdogs, monitors, wardens, and various licensing schemes but at the end of the day if your code works it has to be unlocked somehow so that it can be used.

This is why DRM doesn't work. You want to protect X, but you want someone else to view it. The problem is the person you don't want viewing/using X  and the person you do want using X  are, at some level, *the same person*.

I got so fed up with dealing with 3rd party licensing code (breaking / unregistering / thinking I wasn't a legit user when I was supposed to be) that I became an FSF member. It's not worth my time to work around someone else's restrictions, and it's not worth my time to deal with them. Their code wasn't all that special.

Answer (score 1):

If you're strong naming your assemblies, consider using the [PublisherIdentityPermissionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.publisheridentitypermissionattribute.aspx). You can add this to your DLL and only assemblies signed with the right publisher key will be able to call into that method or class.

This is free and built into the .NET framework. If you need additional features (like the ability to license the DLL to other developers) consider a professional level copy protection tool like our tool [DeployLX Licensing](http://xheo.com/products/copy-protection).

Comment: But can it be decompiled? If so, I prefer the obfuscating options.

Comment: Everything unprotected in .NET can be decompiled. It's part of the platform. If you want to also make your code tamper proof you'll need more than obfuscation. A tool like DeployLX CodeVeil (http://codeveil.com) will use a self dependent encryption key that encrypts a portion of the assembly with code from the other. Any modifications will destroy the encryption key thus corrupting the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add checks in the DLL to verify that the caller is you. But that raises other challenges:

How do you prove that you are you to a DLL. (You could check for something simpler like the current username, but that may not be perfect).

You could require that the exe file is signed by your certificate.

Comment: How can I create those 'Checks'?
I don't mind to change the source code of the assembly having an internal list of authorized Guids etc.

Comment: if(Environment.UserName != "MuUserName")
                throw new Exception("This function is not for you");

The certificate is more complex and not that easy to find a code sample for

Comment: I guess I can prove that i am me because I will be using this DLL from my own code, the question is how can I identify the DLL's caller.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the licensing infrastructure. I have no idea how to implement it, but you use it by creating a .licx file and then, I think, the build process uses the lc.exe tool to do something to embed the license.